# Change view rotation command

Tags: interface

Does anyone know how to change the rotate view command?
The scroll on my mouse is a bit buggy and I can't find it on the keymap.

Comment: Please show your efforts in a screen capture. There is a hand and an axis on the 3D screen so you might able to use this in addition to your mouse scroll.  Edit User Preferences list the keyboard mappings and others can talk about this. I use the on screen axis for view rotation and I enjoy it more than I thought I would. I have some mouse issues as well with ambidextrous mouse. If you can click and drag ... then with the onscreen axis your can rotate view. You can zoom with the hand. You can Pan. Orthogonal Perspective.

Comment: There may be tutorials for the 3D View controls.  Maybe experimentation is enough.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the <kbd>Numpad 4</kbd> and <kbd>Numpad 6</kbd> keys to rotate horizontally, and <kbd>Numpad 8</kbd> and <kbd>Numpad 2</kbd> to rotate vertically.

Also, if you enable "Emulate 3 Button Mouse" in the preferences > Input > mouse section, you can use Left click while holding the Alt key and drag the mouse to rotate the viewport.

Answer (score -3):

[image]

Menu Edit User Preferences.  Then Keymap on left side.
Name Search  `text` ... rotate.
3D View will show the match.